# How to make process explorer show disk active time?

Tags: windows-10, process-explorer

How can you make process explorer show active time like Windows Task Manager?

**EDIT:** My problem is as shown down here in the picture. Some times my hdd is working, but  I won't see it in process explorer, because it doesn't show active time.

[image]

Comment: which value do you mean? Please post a taskmgr picture

Comment: Short Answer: You can't. It's not part of Process Explorer.

Comment: Why? is it not an important detail?

Comment: Why? Because the program has not been written to include this, which means the developer does not understand yet how useful it will be to you. Mark Russinovich can probably be contacted or feedback submitted to inform him of this need.

Comment: have you tried ProcessHacker with the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

`Process Explorer` doesn't support this, but [ProcessHacker 2](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) with the [HardwareDevices](https://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1820) Plugin. So during setup of ProcessHacker 2, make sure you select the HardwareDevices Plugin.

In the plugin dialog, configure the HardwareDevices Plugin to display data of your drives:

[image]

When you open the Systeminformation dialog, you can select the drive and here you see the `Disk Active Time`

[image]